# Renaming variables radare2

Tags: disassembly, radare2

I have a variable called `var_14h` in disassemble code. I want to rename this variable. I try to rename the variable by using the following

```
afvn var_14h i
```

However, radare complains and returns an error:

```
Cant find var by name
```

When i just execute `afv` the variable is listed:

```
var int64_t var_14h @ rbp-0x14
```

I've tried to refer using `rbp-0x14`, `[var_14h]`, however, nothing seems to work. What am i missing?

Answer (score 3):

I think the order of names changed a while ago but if you're using latest from [git](https://github.com/radareorg/radare2) (which you should) the order is reversed

> [0x00005850]> afv?
> Usage:               analyze function arguments/locals
> ...
> | afvn [new_name] ([old_name])  rename argument/local
> | afvt [name] [new_type]        change type for given argument/local
> | afv-([name])                  remove all or given var
> [0x00005850]>

So in your case `afvn i var_14h`.